# CSS borders not appearing

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to style my navigation menu design to reflect the one on timeanddate.com, as seen in this image:

[image]

To create the colors, they're using a simple bottom and left border in CSS.

I'm attempting to add a border to my `<li>` tags on my website sandbox, http://www.escapetech.com:8080.

I'm using the following CSS:

```css
.anylinkcss li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.participate li {
  list-style-type: square;
  border-left-color: #fa514d;
}

#navigation_bar {
  height: 31px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#navigation_bar li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 35px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: auto 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#anylinkmenu3, #anylinkmenu4, #anylinkmenu5, #anylinkmenu6, #anylinkmenu7 {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 18px;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align:left;
  visibility: hidden;
  left:  421px;
  top:207px;
  padding: 7px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

The `#anylinkcss3` and further represent styles for the drop downs, while the `#navigation_bar` styles are for the whole bar. No matter where I add any border styles, none appear, even after I comment out all CSS code and just include a border on these IDs and classes.

My current menu is live at the link I posted above, I would greatly appreciate if someone could take a look and let me know why there may be any issues with borders appearing. This is my first Stack Exchange post so I hope that this was correctly formatted!

Comment: Do you have border-style declared anywhere? it is a required attribute and all border properties will be ignored without it. I do not see it anywhere in your code

Answer (score 10):

Although you set the width and color, you can not leave out the style parameter with borders.

**To get the desired effect as you presented in the image** - [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hsnrw1aj/2/)

- dark background color for the `<ul>`
- a wide border-left on the `<li>`
- a `margin-bottom: 2px` as bottom border - shows `ul` background
- and a few small tweaks like text-indent etc

---

**Some information regarding borders**

CSS borders consist of 3 parameters

- border-width
- border-style
- border-color

You can set one value, which applies to all sides

```
border-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: red;
```

Or with short hand `border: 5px solid red;` and also applies to all sides.

---

You can style each border side individually, as you are doing above.

- border-side-width
- border-side-style
- border-side-color

Example:

```
border-left-width: 5px;
border-left-style: solid; 
border-left-color: white;
```

Which can be accomplished also with shorthand: `border-left: 5px solid white;`

---

For more information and other border opportunities

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style

Answer (score 3):

ahhh... Brian you beat me to it. 
I inserted border-style, and then there is "BORDER"

```
border: 5px solid white;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the trick in his case is that border is applied to the anchor tags not the lists! Cheers! :) And yes if you apply border-color as a property you should also apply border-style and border-width :)